# Pyspark merge multiple columns into a json column with a different column name than dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe (df) like so:

| Product | Region | Order Date | Cost | Revenue | Profit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | R1 | 01-Mar-2023 | 500 | 600 | 100 |
| P1 | R1 | 01-Dec-2022 | 400 | 450 | 50 |
| P2 | R1 | 01-Mar-2023 | 500 | 600 | 100 |
| P2 | R1 | 01-Dec-2022 | 600 | 800 | 200 |

I am trying to find last 3 month and last 6 month details with the below code.

```py
aggr_df = spark.sql(f"""
    SELECT 
        product,
        region,
        SUM(CASE WHEN reporting_period_date >= '{last_3m_first_day}'  THEN cost     ELSE 0 END) last_3m_cost   ,
        SUM(CASE WHEN reporting_period_date >= '{last_3m_first_day}'  THEN revenue  ELSE 0 END) last_3m_revenue,
        SUM(CASE WHEN reporting_period_date >= '{last_3m_first_day}'  THEN profit   ELSE 0 END) last_3m_profit ,
        SUM(CASE WHEN reporting_period_date >= '{last_6m_first_day}'  THEN cost     ELSE 0 END) last_6m_cost   ,
        SUM(CASE WHEN reporting_period_date >= '{last_6m_first_day}'  THEN revenue  ELSE 0 END) last_6m_revenue,
        SUM(CASE WHEN reporting_period_date >= '{last_6m_first_day}'  THEN profit   ELSE 0 END) last_6m_profit 
    FROM 
        fact
    GROUP BY 
        product,
        region
    """)
```

Here last_3m_first_day , last_6m_first_day are 1st day of Last 3 and 6 months respectively.

I get the below output.

| Product | Region | Last_3M_Cost | Last_3M_Revenue | Last_3M_Profit | Last_6M_Cost | Last_6M_Revenue | Last_6M_Profit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | R1 | 500 | 600 | 100 | 900 | 1050 | 150 |
| P2 | R1 | 500 | 600 | 100 | 1100 | 1400 | 300 |

**Here I am trying to convert the 6 fact data to a single json data like below.**

| Product | Region | Last_Month_Details |
| --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | R1 | {"3_MONTHS":"{"cost":500,"revenue":600,"profit":100}","6_MONTHS":"{"cost":900,"revenue":1050,"profit":150}"} |
| P2 | R1 | {"3_MONTHS":"{"cost":500,"revenue":600,"profit":100}","6_MONTHS":"{"cost":1100,"revenue":1400,"profit":300}"} |

How ever I am not able achieve the above format. I have tried the below code.

```py
    aggr_temp_df = aggr_df.select \
        ("product","region", \
         to_json(struct("last_3m_cost","last_3m_revenue","last_3m_profit")).alias("3_MONTHS"), \
         to_json(struct("last_6m_cost","last_6m_revenue","last_6m_profit")).alias("6_MONTHS") \
        )
    
    final_aggr_df = aggr_temp_df.select \
        ("product","region", \
         to_json(struct("3_MONTHS","6_MONTHS")).alias("monthly_aggregate_totals") \
        )
```

I get the below output . Only difference here is I am not able to change the dataframe columns to a different one. **For Ex :  last_3m_cost to cost , last_3m_revenue  to revenue.**

| Product | Region | Last_Month_Details |
| --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | R1 | {"3_MONTHS":"{"Last_3M_Cost":500,"Last_3M_Revenue":600,"Last_3M_Profit":100}","6_MONTHS":"{"Last_6M_Cost":900,"Last_6M_Revenue":1050,"Last_6M_Profit":150}"} |
| P2 | R1 | {"3_MONTHS":"{"Last_3M_Cost":500,"Last_3M_Revenue":600,"Last_3M_Profit":100}","6_MONTHS":"{"Last_6M_Cost":1100,"Last_6M_Revenue":1400,"Last_6M_Profit":300}"} |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with **`create_map`** function with **`lit(<column_name>)` **i.e.**`to_json(create_map(lit(<column_name_desired>),col_name)))`**

**`Example:`**

```
aggr_temp_df = aggr_df.select \
        ("product","region", \
         to_json(create_map(lit("last_3m_cost"),"last_3m_cost",lit("last_3m_revenue"),"last_3m_revenue",lit("last_3m_profit"),"last_3m_profit")).alias("3_MONTHS"), \
         to_json(create_map(lit("last_3m_cost"),"last_3m_cost",lit("last_3m_revenue"),"last_3m_revenue",lit("last_3m_profit"),"last_3m_profit")).alias("6_MONTHS") \
        )
```